# Click on username and get redirected to the profile

Tags: python, django

I'm writing an application and I want to be able to click on the username and go to the profile of the user. I have searched a lot around and didn't find anything that I wanted.

I have something like this:
[image]

I want that when I press on Admin, I will be redirected to the profile with all the information that is saved through the Model that I created.

```
class Farmer(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    province = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    products = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.username
```

How can I achieve something like this?

I thought that I need to write a function inside my views.py but I'm stuck and don't know how to go further.

```
def profile(request):
     # something here..
    return render(request, 'home_page/profile.html')
```

In my project the urlpattern is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('home_page.urls')),
    path('people/', include('people_page.urls')),
]
```

In my app people:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.people, name='people-index'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile-index')
]
```

The template:

```
<div class="sales">
  {%for x in info%}
      <div class="farmer-info">
        <img src="{%static 'people_page/name.png' %}" alt="name icon" />
        <span
          ><a href="{% url 'profile-index'%}">{{ x.name }}</a> <span>{{ x.company_name }}</span>
          <hr
        /></span>
      </div>
  {%endfor%}
```

Comment: So the username should be a link, that's an `<a>` tag inside your template. Nothing to do with the view or the model. Although getting the appropriate href should involve calling the `url` template function with arguments taken from the user's model instance (although much depends on how your URLs are set up).

Comment: @RobinZigmond, yes the Admin is inside an <a> tag inside my template. How can I get the arguments taken from the user's model instance? I will update my post with my template urls.py

Comment: the template and the relevant url from your urlconf, are the relevant things here (EDIT:  your `profile` URL doesn't have any parameters in it, so which user's profile is it for - your own? in that case there is no way to see the profile of another user anyway, you have to make that URL/view/template first)

Comment: Oh, I'm trying to understand what you are telling me. Do I need to do something like this? ```path('profile/<int:id>', views.profile)``` and in my function call ```def profile(request,id)```?

Comment: yes, you need that if you want to allow any user to view any user's profile. (It may be that you only want users to be able to view their own profile, and that's perfectly fine, but if so then I have misinterpreted what you are asking about.)

Comment: I want that everyone can see each others profile. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Farmer

def profile(request, id):
    farmer = get_object_or_404(Farmer, id=id)
    context = {
        'farmer': farmer,
    }
    return render(request, 'home_page/profile.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
path('profile/<id>/', views.profile, name='profile-index')
```

template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'profile-index' x.id %}">{{ x.name }}</a>
```

Comment: Wow, this actually worked. I didn't know how I should fix the template url. Thank you so much and I appreciate that you helped me.

Comment: For completeness - if using app namespaces the url link would be {% url 'app_name:profile-index' x.id %}